# Singularity of Univalent function at $\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

What kind of singularity must a univalent function have at $\infty$?

I do not know how to be rigorous for this problem. I would appreciate if someone can prove this rigorously?

Comment: Starting point: $f$ is univalent in a neighborhood of $\infty$ if and only if $g(z)=f(1/z)$ is univalent in a neighborhood of $0$. (Reason: $z\mapsto 1/z$ is a bijection.)

Comment: You can use the Casorati-Weierstrass theorem plus open mapping theorem (or even easier, the great Picard theorem) to rule out an essential singularity.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, How do I rule out pole? Please help. I am lost totally.